# Can you make Peanut butter flavoured coffee?

Tags: flavored-coffee

Has anyone had any luck making peanut butter flavoured coffee?  If so, what process did you use?

Comment: One way is to use exclusively [quakers](http://www.roastmagazine.com/resources/Roasting101_Articles/Green-Coffee/Roast_JanFeb08_DefectsPt1.pdf) (see esp. p.59) -- these under-ripe beans give one hell of a peanut butter flavour. But that's not very serious. One thing I picked up from a friend was a shot of espresso + milk + spoonful of peanut butter (+ banana) in a blender, but again, that's probably not what you're after. Yeah, good question.

Comment: Do you refer to preparing *before* (dry), during, or after brewing? I suspect the techniques to be pretty different then.

Comment: Thank you for this project idea. Heading to the lab, BRB

Comment: Just saw a poster about aromas of coffee last week. It said that sometimes people keep peanuts with the green beans before roasting. But I imagine you'd be interested in a post-roasting procedure?

Answer (score 4):

### Peanut butter coffee

Inspired by your question I did some experimentation. Peanut butter itself did not work well for me, I could not get it to mix well. I happened to have a powdered penut butter, this worked much better.

[image: Peanut Butter Powder]

I added it like it was powdered cream and sure enough it tasted like peanut butter coffee! The perfect ratio for me seemed to be 2 tbsp per 6 oz cup. It was much better with a little sugar, even though I typically don't add sugar to my coffee. It tasted good, smells great, was more filling then a normal cup of coffee. But the taste was not great, so i won't be drinking it again unless I find a way to improve the taste. The bottom of the cup was very bad because it did not mix fully. So i would recommend blending for anyone who wishes to recreate the coffee treat.

[image]

### Coffee Peanut Butter

While disapointed with PB coffee. Coffee flavor peanut butter is awesome. Specifically Chocolate Coffee Peanut Butter. As its probable inventor it shall now be called Mocha-PB!  Same ingredients as above except use a chocolate flavored powdered Peanut Butter and change the ratios. Use the instructions on the back of the powdered peanut butter but use hot coffee instead of water. Tastes great on a salty cracker or toast.

Comment: Super impressed with your work.  Follow up question, how do you make powdered peanut butter at home?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, probably yielding a more subtle taste is roasting the green beans with the oils of the taste you're going for.

I've once tried, with moderate success, to roast a small batch of butterscotch coffee, since I had the corresponding oil available.

The success was moderate, partly because it was a pan roast, and I'm still new at this, however it makes for a fun experiment, and introduces you to the roasting process (as if I needed to fixate on coffee more..).

A nice roasting guide is [here](http://www.angelfire.com/pro2/panroastingcoffee/howtopanroastcoffee2.html/). When the part where the bean oils start to develop comes, that's where you throw in no more than 4 or 5 teaspoons of the oil with the flavor you want. Of course, you can adjust this with smell, and depending on the amount of beans you're roasting. You then go on with the process according to instructions.

For peanut butter flavour, since I found no PB oil with a quick search, I'd add the oil on top of a jar, or mix concentrated oils that make something near the yummy PB flavor